# Orthogonal matching pursuit

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection, dimension-reduction

I run orthogonal matching pursuit algorithm in python and get the following warning:

RuntimeWarning:  Orthogonal matching pursuit ended prematurely due to linear dependence in the dictionary. The requested precision might not have been met.

How should I remove the linear dependency in my dictionary?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Linear dependence in the dictionary" exception in sklearns OMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131696/linear-dependence-in-the-dictionary-exception-in-sklearns-omp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131696/linear-dependence-in-the-dictionary-exception-in-sklearns-omp). Have you tried normalizing both the data array `y` and the dictionary `X`?