# How to fix "RuntimeWarning: Orthogonal matching pursuit ended prematurely due to linear dependence in the dictionary

Tags: python

I was looking for a library to try compressed sensing in Python. And I found a great library and sample. Then I copied and pasted it according to the sample procedure, but the following error occurred. I do not know how to fix this error. Please answer if there is a solution.

Here are the sites I referenced:

https://github.com/hacarus/spm-image/blob/development/examples/ksvd_inpainting.ipynb

The following is the content of the error:

```
/Users/myname/.pyenv/versions/spm-image/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/dict_learning.py:171: RuntimeWarning:  Orthogonal matching pursuit ended prematurely due to linear
dependence in the dictionary. The requested precision might not have been met.

  copy_Xy=copy_cov).T
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Linear dependence in the dictionary" exception in sklearns OMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131696/linear-dependence-in-the-dictionary-exception-in-sklearns-omp)

Comment: I saw the article but I did not understand. if you have the time, please explain to me.